# Prove that $f(z)=\begin{cases} \frac{ \overline{z}^3}{z^2} & z \neq 0\\0 & z=0\end{cases}$ is continuous at $0$ but $f'(0)$ doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}  \frac{ \overline{z}^3}{z^2}  & z  \neq 0\\0 & z=0\end{cases}$$

prove that $f(z) $ is continuous at $z=0$ but $f'(0)$ doesn't exist.

I think maybe using Cauchy-Riemann equations will help to show $f'(0)$ does not exist but I have no idea about the rest.

Comment: I would suggest showing $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=f(0)$. This gives you continuity at $z=0$ and is easy to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, for each $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$,$$\left|\frac{\overline z^3}{z^2}\right|=|z|.$$you have $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=0=f(0)$.

But, if $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$,$$\frac{f(z)-f(0)}z=\frac{\overline z^3}{z^3}.$$So,$$x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\implies\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=1,$$but$$x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\implies\frac{f(xi)-f(0)}{xi}=-1,$$and therefore the limit$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}z$$doesn't exist. In other words, $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.